# How to remove leading zeros from an alphanumeric string using liquid map?

Tags: shopify, liquid, azure-logic-apps

I would like to remove leading zeros from an alphanumeric string using liquid map, I have not found any builtin function to perform the same action.
I can try the same with C# using reguler expression but in liquid map regex is not working

```
// C# code
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = "0000032123hhf00ff00";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"^0+", "");
Console.WriteLine( $"value is :{ output}"); // Output: "32123hhf00ff00"

Console.ReadLine();
```

NOTE: Liquid map I am trying to use from logic app.
the same I can test it from.
https://geekplayers.com/run-liquild-online.html

Comment: It is not possible by doing with liquid, if you want i can give with inbuilt functions

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove leading zeros from an alphanumeric string using liquid map?

Using Liquid Map currently this type of operation is not possible, AFAIK.

So, simply I have used built-in Functions to this Operation.

**`Design:`**

[image]

Below is the function which worked for me:

```
substring(variables('var'),indexOf(variables('var'),first(replace(variables('var'),'0',''))))
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Hope this solves your issue(alternatively but in Logic app itself using just one compose function).

Comment: Question is about using liquid map, not with logic app functions

Comment: "Using Liquid Map currently this type of operation is not possible". This I have mentioned in answer, I have provided an alternative!!